# Checking a stream in kilobytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, stream

I want to check if my stream is over 100 kilobytes.

I have this:

```
   int size = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength/1024;
        if (size<100)
        {
```

Is this the way to do it?

Another thing that I want to know, is how can I autosize a picture into an image control.

I remember that the winform image control has an autosize property..But I dont see one in asp image control

Comment: Please don't ask two different questions in one. It makes searching for it and finding a good answer much harder later on. You should ask a spearate question for your second problem.

Comment: Regarding image, just give it fixed width or height, and the other dimension will be calculated automatically by the browser itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a right to do it, yes

For the ImageControl: Just set the height and width for the imagecontrol and the image will scale. If you dont set any height and width the control sets the appropiate height and width itself

```
<asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" Height="400" Width="400" ImageUrl="WHATEVERURLHERE" />
```

Comment: This better be posted as comment, it doesn't justify Answer.

Comment: I can't see why I have to elaborate the first question. It simply is the right way to do it :) And for the second question I have provided details

Comment: Nice answer Martin. All I wanted to know

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.contentlength.aspx) the `ContentLength` is the lenght in bytes, so yes this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the `<` operator, so you are checking if the stream is *under* 100 kilobytes.

Use the `>=` operator to check if the stream is 100 kilobytes or more:

```
int size = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength / 1024;
if (size >= 100) {
  ...
}
```

To set the size of an image you would set it's width and/or height using the `width` and `height` styles in CSS, or the `width` and `height` HTML attributes in the image tag.

Comment: Thats right, i want the size of the stream to be no more than 100 kilobytes

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd: So you downvoted my answer because I answered what you actually asked about, not what you meant to ask about?